# Invalidate metadata gives TableNotFoundException although I can see the table in the list of tables

Tags: shell, sh, impala

I am trying to run a script that validates if all the tables that are supposed to be created as a part of my deployment. This is my script:

```
set -x

ENV=$1

. /user/setenv.sh

ticket=""
wlf_kinit ticket

echo "Checking if Kerberos Ticket is available.."
    klist $ticket

    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Kerberos Ticket not found..Exiting"
        exit 1
    fi

echo "Validating Hadoop tables" > /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt

db_dir=/user/db

cd $db_dir

for current_directory in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
    #current_directory=`echo $current_directory | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'`
    echo $current_directory

    if [ "$current_directory" != "." ]; then
        current_directory=`echo $current_directory | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'`
        if [ "${current_directory:0:1}" = "v" ]; then
            dir=$db_dir/$current_directory/views
        else    
            dir=$db_dir/$current_directory/tables
        fi  
        cd $dir
        pwd
        #echo "Validating tables in "$current_directory >> /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt
        find . -name '*.hql' | while read rec; do
        echo $rec
        tbl_name=`echo $rec | awk -F '/' '{print $2}' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`
        result=$(impala-shell --quiet --delimited --ssl -i ${impala_host} -ku ${user_id}${impala_realm} -q "set request_pool = ${request_pool}; use $current_directory$ENV; invalidate metadata $tbl_name; show tables like '$tbl_name';") 2>> /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt
        #echo $result

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

            if [ ${result} == ${tbl_name} ]; then
                echo "$tbl_name exists" #>> /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt
            else
                echo "$tbl_name does not exist"  #>> /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt
            fi
        else
            echo $current_directory$ENV"."$tbl_name" Query error" >> /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt
            impala-shell --quiet --delimited --ssl -i ${impala_host} -ku ${user_id}${impala_realm} -q "set request_pool = ${request_pool}; use $current_directory$ENV; invalidate metadata $tbl_name; show tables like '$tbl_name';" 2>> /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt

        fi
        done
    fi      
done

cat /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt | mail -a  /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt -s 'Hadoop DB validation completed. Check the attached log.'  -r ${from_email} ${to_email} 2>> /tmp/psk1/db_validation_log.txt

kdestroy -c $ticket
```

This script prints the failed queries to a .txt file and sends it in an email. In the text file I see some of the queries failing with TableNotFoundException. But when I open the impala shell and list out the tables, I am able to see the table in the list. I am not sure what is causing this inconsistency.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you try those commands manually ? are they giving results  ? Just confirming your script is checking correct location and have suitable access rights with your shell script. !

Comment: @Sandesh Thanks for your comment. Yes, I ran the individual commands manually and there were no errors. I am only getting the query failures when I run the script.

Comment: The script looks alright , i just feel some variables are not getting set properly (like env) , probably you can trace the flow using some log file. Redirect step by step execution to a log and probably see if things are going wrong somewhere :)

Comment: Does your table name include the database the table is in? Because if it is looking at the wrong database then it would produce this error.